# System.ArgumentNullException when creating a GUID

Tags: c#

This makes no sense, reflection and exception lead me to believe that there is nothing at all wrong with this, however I get a `System.ArgumentNullException` on the following line no matter what.

```
Guid testGuid = new Guid("745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da");
```

throws;

```
System.ArgumentNullException occurred
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: g
  ParamName=g
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
  InnerException:
```

I even SS'd it to ensure you guys I'm not losing my mind.
[image]

So any ideas what could be happening here?

Comment: It is much more likely that it is the previous statement that has this problem and the debugger is just slightly confused about the location. Can you verify that `(string)instance.GetPropertyValue("classGuid")` returns a non-null value?

Comment: [No repro on .NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QsF456).  Are you sure there's no other code that's throwing that exception?

Comment: I thought that as well, but hovering over the previous var shows that its populated with a valid GUID.

Comment: The full call stack will show you everything you need to know. It looks like this is not the code you're debugging.

Comment: I suppose what Lasse said - the line numbers in debugging information can go out of sync sometimes. close VS, delete all BIN and OBJ folders in the solution, and retry and see if the exception is reported one line earlier. also, simply put on a breakpoint there and see in Watch if that getpropvalue returns null

Comment: Is this RELEASE or DEBUG build?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl it does seem to be coming from the GUID constructor though

Comment: Wobbles - if debuginfo went out of sync with the code, then neither linenumbers, nor code highlight locations, nor "hovering" will get you correct results. Maaybe 'watch' window will, but not always. Clean, really clean (delete bin/obj), rebuild, retry.

Comment: Try using Guid.Parse. If there's something wrong with the format then you should get a FormatException instead.

Comment: @Wobbles I ran your code but did not have any error, would you say your version of visual studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is on the previous line. The Visual Studio debugger sometimes shows one line further. Normally, it goes to the correct line when you press "Enable editing" but you don't have that option according to the screenshot.

(I never understood why this commonly occurring bug is not fixed.)

Comment: The OP mentioned that the `classGuid` has a value though...

Comment: Maybe it's in a loop and it's a previous value? The OP now needs to add an assert and watch it fail.

Comment: It never occurred to me that the management object may be constructed incorrectly and not have all properties, that was infact a bug in my code but the bugs in VS prevented me from correctly identifying it....

Comment: The idea of it being from a previous loop was correct aswell. 2 debugging bugs in vs converged to cause me one heck of a headache this morning.